# what is the alternate way to do a function based on window width jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show the button and hide the stuff when the width <450, if >450, do the switch way, hide the button and show the stuff. There is no problem to hide and show with the css code, but the problem is once I click the button in <450, the stuff show up, if I go back to >450 screen, the button will not hide again. I had tried to put window.resize in the jquery, it give me weird performance. Click run the code to see it. Appreciate.

```js
if ($(window).width() < 450) {

var show_stuff=$('#all_vote_menu');
var button_menu=$('#button');

      $(button_menu).on('click', function(){
   
   $(show_stuff).show(400,'swing');
   $(button_menu).hide();
      
  });
  
  $(document).mouseup(function (e){
     if (!show_stuff.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
         && show_stuff.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
     { 

   $(show_stuff).hide(400,'swing');
   $(button_menu).fadeIn();
  
     }
 });
  }
```

```css
#button{
     display:none ;/*hide when >450px*/
     
   }
   .all_vote_menu{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background:yellow;
   }

@media screen and (max-width: 450px)  {

#button{
     display:block ;/*show when <450px*/
     color:green;
   }
   .all_vote_menu{
    display:none;/*hide when <450px*/
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button" name="all_vote_show" value="Menu"/>
<div class="all_vote_menu" id='all_vote_menu'>hello</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of the width check and add the event all the time. Other option would be to listen to window resize and add/remove the event.

Comment: I had tried to get rid of the width check, but then the button will show up and hide the stuff in all width.

Comment: Add width check in the if where you show the stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the width check `if ($(window).width() < 450) {`

Add check in the if that is doing the showing

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    if ($(window).width() >= 450 && !show_stuff.is(e.target) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, I change it to <=450, it actually works as I expect if the <450, button show up, >450, button hide, stuff showed. But still a little problem here, in <450, if I click the button, once I go back to bigger screen >450, stuff will not show in >450, but when I click the screen, the stuff showed

Answer (score 2):

you don´t need the if condition to verify the window width because the button is only accessible when the window is smaller then 450px.

remove this and it works.

[Try this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmxz5Lcg/)

jquery code:

```
var show_stuff=$('#all_vote_menu');
var button_menu=$('#button');

        $(button_menu).on('click', function(){

            $(show_stuff).show(400,'swing');
            $(button_menu).hide();

        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e){
        if (!show_stuff.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && show_stuff.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {   

            $(show_stuff).hide(400,'swing');
            $(button_menu).fadeIn();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however, the button will show up in all width. epascarello's answer will make the button disappear if >450, though it need to refresh page.